# IntegrationTest & SpringApplicationConfiguration in SpringBoot 2.2.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have a project with these dependencies:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
```

and this class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApp.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest
public class ServiceTest extends TestCase {

    public void testAllNames() {
    }
}
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'IntegrationTest'
Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringApplicationConfiguration'
```

Comment: Using `extends TestCase ` is JUnit 3 ... if you use `@RunWith` this is JUnit 4 furthermore test have to be annotated with `@Test` ... ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntegrationTest` was deprecated sine spring boot 1.x. You can use `SpringBootTest` instead.